# Python template with list of values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-templates

I am new with python template. I need to create following output by using python template. It is basically contains a database table name and it's attribute information in triple form.

```
fuse: MIAMI_HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual
fuse: MIAMI_HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 rdf:type fuse:OracleTable

fuse: MIAMI_HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 fuse: hasColumn fuse:SUBLOC_1
fuse: MIAMI_HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 fuse: hasColumn fuse:PURPOSE
fuse: MIAMI_HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 fuse: hasColumn fuse:DURATION

fuse: SUBLOC_1  rdf:type    fuse:Column
fuse: SUBLOC_1  rdf:type    owl:NamedIndividual
fuse: PURPOSE   rdf:type    fuse:Column
fuse: PURPOSE  rdf:type     owl:NamedIndividual
fuse: DURATION  rdf:type    fuse:Column
fuse: DURATION  rdf:type    owl:NamedIndividual
```

Attribute list may vary based on number of columns in the table. I tried following.

```
def add_table(table_name=None, attribute=None): 

#table_name: MIAMI_HOUSEHOLD_2009_1
#attribute=['SUBLOC_1', 'PURPOSE', 'DURATION']
add_table_ttl_template = Template(
"""fuse:${table_name} rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual, \n\t 
fuse:${table_name} rdf:type fuse:OracleTable , \n\t ". """)
for att in attribute:
    fuse: ${table_name} rdf:hasColumn fuse: ${att}, \n\t 
    fuse: ${att} rdf:type fuse:Column, \n\t 
    fuse: ${att} rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual 

add_table_ttl_template = add_table_ttl_template.substitute(locals())
```

I think it is wrong. Can anyone help me to correct it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you *think* it's wrong and what should be the correct result? If you get an error, don't forget to post the full traceback.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks!